# Docusign Webhook TLS exception

Tags: docusignconnect, snaplogic

When DocuSign tries to call my API it throws a TLS exception, how can I solve this?

**Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 7f48081c-4fb1-48c5-a97a-66498625a892 :: https://dapi.altertude.com/api/1/rest/feed-master/queue/GTC_Dev/apim/DocuSign/1.0.1/Docusignwebhook :: Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a TLS certificate for HTTPS connections that is issued by a well-known CA, such as those listed in the Microsoft Trusted Root program. Using a self-signed certificate or any of the free certificates from untrusted CAs will not work.